# Bind 9 DNSSEC not returning SERVFAIL when it should

Tags: dns, bind, validation

So I just installed bind 9.11.36 on Almalinux 9.1 and it is not validating DNSSEC as expected.  Looking up [www.dnssec-failed.org](http://www.dnssec-failed.org) should fail validation.  The results are missing the ad flag as expected yet I am not getting SERVFAIL and it gives the answer which it should not.

My query was dig [www.dnssec-failed.org](http://www.dnssec-failed.org) @127.0.0.1

My log says... validating [www.dnssec-failed.org/A](http://www.dnssec-failed.org/A): no valid signature found yet nslookup and dig both give me a valid result without the expected SERVFAIL.   WHY???

```
   dig www.dnssec-failed.org @127.0.0.1
   
   ; <<>> DiG 9.16.23-RH <<>> www.dnssec-failed.org. @127.0.0.1 A
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50810
   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
   
   ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
   ; COOKIE: 0a21031e4e1f7243010000006424706502d5d67190cfe7eb (good)
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;www.dnssec-failed.org.         IN      A
   
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   www.dnssec-failed.org.  5489    IN      A       69.252.193.191
   www.dnssec-failed.org.  5489    IN      A       68.87.109.242
   
   ;; Query time: 0 msec
   ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
   ;; WHEN: Wed Mar 29 10:07:49 PDT 2023
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 110
   
    > nslookup www.dnssec-failed.org
   Server:         127.0.0.1
   Address:        127.0.0.1#53
   
   Non-authoritative answer:
   Name:   www.dnssec-failed.org
   Address: 69.252.193.191
   Name:   www.dnssec-failed.org
   Address: 68.87.109.242
```

My named.conf is pretty simple,

```
    options {
            listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.9.82; 10.1.2.35; 216.151.2.125; };
            directory       "/var/named";
            datasize        10G;
            max-cache-size  10G;
            dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
            statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
            memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
            secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
            recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
            allow-query     { localhost; 192.168.9.0/24; 10.1.2.0/24; 216.151.2.96/27; };
    
            recursion yes;
            dnssec-validation yes;
    
            managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
            geoip-directory "/usr/share/GeoIP";
    
            pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
            session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
    
            /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
            include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
    };
    
    logging {
            channel default_debug {
                    file "data/named.run";
                    severity dynamic;
            };
            category lame-servers {null;};
    };
    
    include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
    include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I would appreciate any clues as to where to look next.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to auto and had the same result but I DID find the answer to the question and I will post it here.

The problem was in the file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config  I compared it to the same file on a properly working server and it was very different.  I changed it to match the working server and BAM, it started working.

This may be too much info but here are both files.

The one that works...

```
disable-algorithms "." {
RSAMD5;
DSA;
};
disable-ds-digests "." {
GOST;
};
```

The one that failed...

```
disable-algorithms "." {
RSAMD5;
RSASHA1;
NSEC3RSASHA1;
DSA;
};
disable-ds-digests "." {
SHA-1;
GOST;
};
```

I am not sure but I suspect the reason was disabling NSEC3RSASHA1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok so maybe I didn't describe my answer well.    The file included in the named.conf /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config  has algorithms and digests that are disabled.  I replaced that file with the one from another working server and it fixed the problem.  Apparently some of those disabled algorithms were needed to  make the validation work.  I never did go any further to see which algorithm it was but I suspect it was NSEC3RSASHA1.

I installed bind on both a Almalinux 8 and an Almalinux 9.1 box.    The Almalinus 8 worked right out of the box.  The Almalinux 9.1 did not.

Answer (score 0):

You have `dnssec-validation` set to `yes`. The options are `yes`, `no` and `auto`.

When set to `yes`, a DNSSEC trust anchor must be manually configured using a `trust-anchors` statement (or possibly two other deprecated statements). I don't see such a statement in your configuration.

[The latest release of the BIND 9 Configuration Reference](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#namedconf-statement-dnssec-validation) says:

> If set to yes, DNSSEC validation is enabled, but a trust anchor must be manually configured using a `trust-anchors` statement (or the `managed-keys` or `trusted-keys` statements, both deprecated). **If there is no configured trust anchor, validation does not take place.**

You might want to set `dnssec-validation` to `auto` instead. That would allow BIND to use its built-in root DNSSEC trust anchor, and update it automatically as needed. If you don't want to do that, the alternative is to fetch the root trust anchor yourself [from IANA](https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files), applying whatever verification procedures you feel sufficient.

If you want to add private DNS zones without implementing DNSSEC on them, you might declare them like this:

```
validate-except { "home.arpa"; };
```

To use `home.arpa` zone (the recommended name for private home networks according to [RFC 8375](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8375.html), guaranteed to not conflict with anything official), you may also need:

```
disable-empty-zone "home-arpa";
```